# Syntax for using Promise.all() result to perform another query

Tags: node.js, express, promise, promise.all

I have a `Promise.all()` that performs two queries one after the other. In the result of the `Promise.all()` I want to perform a third query using the result from the second query.

How would I create a `function()` that I can cleanly use inside the `Promise()`?

```
Promise
    .all([upsertDeviceId, createEndpoint])
    .then((values) => {

        const upsertDeviceIdResult = values[0];
        const createEndpoint       = values[1];

        if(upsertDeviceIdResult.upsertedCount > 0){
            //Perform third query here
            //performThirdQuery(createEndpoint.EndpointArn);
        }
        
        return res.status(200).send({ success: true });

    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({ reason: 'unknown' });
    });
});
```

What I can't figure out is how can I listen to the results of this third query and
return a `return res.status(200).send({ success: true });`

or an err.

`return res.status(500).send({ success: false});`

```
function performThirdQuery(resultFromSecondQuery) {
        const updateDeviceIdEndpointArn = db.collection('deviceids')
            .updateOne(
                { device_id: deviceId },
                { $set: { device_endpoint_arn: deviceId } }
            );
    }
```

Comment: *"I have a Promise.all() that performs two queries one after the other"* That isn't what `Promise.all` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a `Promise.all()` that performs two queries one after the other

That isn't what `Promise.all` does. Both operations run in parallel, both having been started when you got `upsertDeviceId` and `createEndpoint` (which are presumably promises you got from somewhere else), and `Promise.all` waits for them both to be fulfilled before fulfilling its promise (or waits for one of them to reject before rejecting its promise).

But assuming that you did want to run them in parallel, what you usually do is return the result of the third query (which won't run until both of the previous ones complete):

```
Promise
    .all([upsertDeviceId, createEndpoint])
    .then((values) => {

        const upsertDeviceIdResult = values[0];
        const createEndpoint       = values[1];

        if(upsertDeviceIdResult.upsertedCount > 0){
            return performThirdQuery(createEndpoint.EndpointArn);
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        res.status(200).send({ success: true });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send({ reason: 'unknown' });
    });
});
```

Note the `return` before `performThirdQuery`. Assuming `performThirdQuery` returns a promise, this resolves the promise from that first fulfillment handler to the promise from `performThirdQuery` (when you resolve a promise *to* another promise, it makes the former's result determined by the latter's result). In the other case (`upsertDeviceIdResult.upsertedCount > 0` isn't true), the handler just implicitly returns `undefined`. The second fulfillment handler runs when the promise from the first handler is fulfilled, either immediately with `undefined` or, when `upsertDeviceIdResult.upsertedCount > 0` **is** true, when that promise is fulfilled.

In modern environments (including any vaguely recent version of Node.js), you can use an `async` function and `await` instead:

```
// (In an `async` function)
const [upsertDeviceIdResult, createEndpoint] = await Promise.all([upsertDeviceId, createEndpoint]);
try {
    if (upsertDeviceIdResult.upsertedCount > 0) {
        await performThirdQuery(createEndpoint.EndpointArn);
    }
    res.status(200).send({ success: true });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send({ reason: 'unknown' });
}
```

---

Side note — Instead of:

```
    .then((values) => {

        const upsertDeviceIdResult = values[0];
        const createEndpoint       = values[1];
        // ...
```

you can use destructuring in the parameter list:

```
    .then(([upsertDeviceIdResult, createEndpoint]) => {
        // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. And also wow, thanks a bunch for this extremely well rounded answer :)

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE - :-) Happy coding!